# PHP/Mysql style output data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to style my output data, but I do not know how exactly do this.

My code looks like this:

```
$Sql99 = "SELECT Cat_Name, Cat_Id, COUNT(Product_Id) AS itemcount FROM tabproducts 
      INNER JOIN tabcats ON tabproducts.Cat_Id = tabcats.Cat_Id  
      GROUP BY tabproducts.Cat_Id ORDER BY itemcount DESC LIMIT 0,4";
$Query99 = mysql_query($Sql99, $Conn);
while($Rs99 = mysql_fetch_array($Query99)){ 

 $cats .= "<li><a href=\"\">".$Rs99["Cat_Name"]."</a></li>"; //this is fine


 $Sql08 = "SELECT tabproducts.*
      FROM tabproducts
      WHERE tabproducts.Cat_Id = '".$Rs99["Cat_Id"]."' ORDER BY Product_Id DESC
      LIMIT 0,5";
$Query08 = mysql_query($Sql08, $Conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($Rs08 = mysql_fetch_array($Query08)){

//OUTPUT

}
 }
```

My problem is on the second select the information I am try do output should look like this:

```
      <div>
        <ul class="home-listagem-empresas"> //categorie 1
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="home-listagem-empresas"> //categorie 2
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="home-listagem-empresas"> //categorie 3
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="home-listagem-empresas"> //categorie 4
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Each `ul` with the `li`'s will represent the results from the 4 categories.

Sorry if I cannot explain it well, my English is not very good.

Comment: Do the output correctly with the DIV UL and LI's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem is that you are unable to present the data in a way that is convenient for you. These types of problems (nested loops) occur a lot in application development and you should probably look into practicing basic algorithms for this. [Here](http://www.primitivetype.com/articles/php_nested_for_loops.php) are a [couple](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-loops) of tutorials to help you out.

That being said, to obtain the output you desire, you would do this:

```
$cats .= "<div><ul class='home-listagem-empresas'>";
while($Rs08 = mysql_fetch_array($Query08)){
  //OUTPUT
  $cats .= "<li><h1>".$Rs08["Product_Name"]."</h1></li>";
}
$cats .= "</ul></div>";
```

All the best,

Comment: Thanks for the help @KerrM i was on right way my mistake was on the first $cats for open the div i was doing $cats = and not .=   thanks again.